# Grails promise callback not called

Tags: multithreading, grails, asynchronous, promise

I can't get a callback to be executed that should be called from with a Promise onComplete().

```
// some service
def initiateDbLoad() {
    def p1 = task { dbLoad() }
    p1.onComplete { result ->           
        dbLoadCallback()
    }
}

def dbLoad() {
    // some long-running process here
}

def dbLoadCallback() {
    // I am never called
}
```

The use case is that I want to kick off a long-running process in a separate thread.  The calling thread should return, not wait for the thread to finish.  When the long-running process is complete, I want it to execute a callback.  Is this possible?  Or should it look like the code below?

```
def initiateDbLoad() {
    def p1 = task {
        dbLoad()
        dbLoadCallback()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you also added an `onError` to test, if there is one?  how do you determine, that it is not run?  logging?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I thought onComplete was called every time, not just only on successful completion.  It was failing and onError caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onComplete` is only called on success.  You have to add an `onError` too to get actual errors.